# Make CakePHP use local PHPUnit & PHPUnit Selenium installed via Composer

Tags: php, cakephp, selenium, phpunit

On my computer I have a CakePHP Project. And inside the cakephp project I have a `composer.json` file like below:

```
{
    "name": "a/b",
    "description": "c",
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
    },
    "license": "Proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "d",
            "email": "e"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "f"
}
```

After running `composer install` I have phpunit and the selenium package installed and working here

`/cakephpproject/vendor/bin/phpunit`
`/cakephpproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium`

Now from the `/cakephpproject/app/` I tried to run the following command

`../vendor/bin/phpunit Test/Case/Controller/MyControllerTest`

But I am receiving the following error message

> Fatal error: Class 'App' not found...

If I use `./Console/cake test app Controller/GranulesController` the test does attempt to run but throws the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase not found` error since on the system PHPUnit Selenium is not installed.

How do I make cakephp use the phpunit & the phpunit-selenium I installed using composer and not use the phpunit installed globally?

Answer (score 0):

The following command seems to be executing the PHPUnit & PHPUnit-Selenium2 I installed using Composer.

```
./Console/cake test app AllControllers --bootstrap ../vendor/autoload.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in CakePHP 2.x (it was fixed in the latest CakePHP 2.8.5).

[CakePHP expects](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php#L135) to find PHPUnit in one of the following places:

1. `vendors/phpunit/phpunit`
2. `vendors/PHPUnit`
3. `vendors/phpunit.phar`
4. `app/Vendor/phpunit`
5. `app/Vendor/PHPUnit`
6. `app/Vendor/phpunit.phar`
7. `[Composer's global directory]/vendor/phpunit`
8. `[Composer's global directory]/vendor/PHPUnit`
9. `[Composer's global directory]/vendor/phpunit.phar`

But Composer (by default) [creates a directory called `vendor` for its files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) (note the lack of a plural).

This issue was [recently fixed for CakePHP 2.x](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/c02b269bcb85d45b37235248ac7515b8cd338198), but you can get the same behaviour by setting [the `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR` environment variable](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-vendor-dir) to `vendors`.